# Laravel paginate pivot tables

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table

I have collections which contains custom products I need to paginate those collections products but I receive error.

## data

1. With this query I can get my collection and it's products but I'm not able to paginate products.

> $collection = Collection::where('slug', $slug)->where('status',
>   'active')->with('products')->first();

2. With this query I receive error

> $collection = Product::with('collections')->whereHas('collections',
>   function($query) use($slug) {   $query->where('slug',
>   $slug)->where('status', 'active')->first(); });

#### Error

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'shopping.product_id' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `collection_products` inner join `product_id` on `collection_products`.`id` = `product_id`.`collection_product_id` where `products`.`id` = `product_id`.`product_id` and `slug` = test and `status` = active limit 1)
```

## Code

`Product model`

```
public function collections()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(CollectionProduct::class, 'product_id');
    }
```

`Collection model`

```
public function collection(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(CollectionProduct::class);
    }

    public function products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'collection_products', 'collection_id', 'product_id');
    }
```

`CollectionProduct model`

```
public function collection()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Collection::class, 'collection_id','id');
    }
```

`Controller` *default query*

```
public function single($slug){
  $collection = Collection::where('slug', $slug)->where('status', 'active')->with('products')->first();
  return view('front.collections.single', compact('collection'));
}
```

## Question

1. How can I get my collection products with pagination ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things:

You are trying to call the `first()` method inside of a relationship query in this line:

> $collection = Product::with('collections')->whereHas('collections', function($query) use($slug) { $query->where('slug', $slug)->where('status', 'active')->first(); });

The methods `first()` and `get()` are used to execute the query, so you should keep them at the end of the chain of eloquent methods:

```
$collection = Product::with('collections')
                     ->whereHas('collections', function($query) use($slug) { 
                         $query->where('slug', $slug)->where('status', 'active'); 
                     })
                     ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-models

However, if you want to paginate the list of products, then what you really want is the `paginate()` method:

```
$collection = Product::with('collections')
                     ->whereHas('collections', function($query) use($slug) { 
                         $query->where('slug', $slug)->where('status', 'active'); 
                     })
                     ->paginate(20);   // will return 20 products per page
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination

Also, the `collections()` method on your `Product` model has `product_id` listed as the join table, and is joining to the `CollectionProduct` model instead of the `Collection` model.

Try this instead for your `Product` model:

```
public function collections()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Collection::class, 'collection_products', 'product_id', 'collection_id');
}
```

Comment: it returns `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'shopping.product_id' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `products` where exists (select * from `collection_products` inner join `product_id` on `collection_products`.`id` = `product_id`.`collection_product_id` where `products`.`id` = `product_id`.`product_id` and `slug` = test and `status` = active))`

Comment: @mafortis Can you post the table definitions for each of the models? Add them to your question above.

Comment: @mafortis nvm, I think I found the issue. See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks, i removed my solution and will accept yours instead

Answer (score 0):

i use following code and working very well

the first step get product

```
$product = Product()->find($product_id);
```

than i get collections and pagination

```
$collections = Product::find($product_id)->collections->paginate(20);
```

for example i used above code in this [site](https://ragalawyers.com/).